# Print a line giving by a number in variable

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I try to get a line by a giving number in a variable so i try awk command:

i did :

```
DATE_ISSUE_OPIT_SIP="31456
12390
11232
12222"

COUNTER_NUMBER=1
line=$(awk 'NR==$COUNTER_NUMBER' <<< "$Date_ISSUE_OPIT_SIP")
```

Output is empty.

I want the output like this for example :

```
COUNTER_NUMBER=2
line=$(awk 'NR==$COUNTER_NUMBER' <<< "$Date_ISSUE_OPIT_SIP")
echo $line
11232
```

Thank's for help

Comment: `line=$(awk -v cn=$COUNT_NUMBER 'NR==cn' <<< "$Date_ISSUE_OPIT_SIP"`

Comment: Also, in shell, case matters.  The variable `Date_ISSUE_OPIT_SIP` is undefined.  You likely meant `DATE_ISSUE_OPIT_SIP`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix will be replacing single quotes with double quotes

```
... awk "NR==$COUNTER_NUMBER" <<< "$DATE_ISSUE_OPIT_SIP"
```

note also that the variable names you used didn't match, it's case sensitive.

Comment: I don't think your solution works in a pure Posix shell. While bash and Zsh have `<<<`, Posix does not have it, AFIK.

Comment: That's copied over from OP.

Answer (score 0):

Awk has a wonderly easy way of setting an internal variable by passing it on the command line:

```
txt="31456
12390
11232
12222"

n=2
line=$(awk 'NR==counter' counter=$n <<< "$txt")
echo "$line"
12390
```

It also means you can't easily have a file with an `=` in the name.

You can also do:

```
line=$(awk -v counter=$n 'NR==counter' <<< "$txt")
```

Note: `NR` starts at 1. So to get the 3rd line, you would pass 3 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK with sed too

```
sed "$COUNTER_NUMBER"'!d' <<< "$DATE_ISSUE_OPIT_SIP"
```